# How to specify executable python path?

Tags: command-line, bash, path

My `PATH` variable looks like this:

```
/home/elgin/anaconda3/bin:…:/usr/bin:…
```

As you see above `anaconda3` precedes `/usr/bin`. So when I type `python` in terminal, it gets `python` in the first `anaconda3` path.

How can I tell bash terminal to load `python` in `/usr/bin/` instead of the one in `anaconda3`? Is there any argument that I can pass for doing this or I should edit `PATH` each time?

Comment: Why not just rearrange the directories in your PATH? Can’t you do this in your `.bashrc` file where the Anaconda directories are added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way with `alias`:

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python
```

Please see [*In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it only once, just type

```
/usr/bin/python
```

(instead of just `python`).
If this situation comes up often, you can save typing by defining an alias.

If you want `python` to be interpreted as `/usr/bin/python`
for many commands in a row, it may be simpler to edit PATH. 
You can write a shell function to do that,
to reduce typing and reduce the risk of typographical errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No, I don't want python to be interpreted as '/usr/bin/python' always. In my case, I think using alias and assigning python to a variable is more suitable, since I use 'python' command multiple times in one terminal session.